# Error: No tidy method for objects of class function :: broom.mixed

Tags: r, broom, tidymodels

I am trying to perform a linear regression fit using `tidymodels`,`parsnip` but encounters the following error:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class function
```

routine:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(parsnip)
library(broom.mixed)

linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm") %>% 
  fit(formula = cnt ~ temp_raw, data = bikeshare)
fit %>% tidy()
fit %>% glance()
```

Having read this post [Tidy function gives this error: No tidy method for objects of class lmerMod. It will not work on my computer, but works in pdf with same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855115/tidy-function-gives-this-error-no-tidy-method-for-objects-of-class-lmermod-it)

and I tried `broom.mixed` but still the error persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you need to assign the fitted model to an object; in your case it would also be `fit`.

There are two other points to consider:

- it's confusing/not best practice to assign variables with the same name as R functions (i.e. you might want to call your fit `fit0` or `my_fit` or something rather than `fit`); usually you can get away with it but it breaks, confusingly, in some contexts
- `broom.mixed` is a red herring. The `broom` package is actually used for `lm` fits (and you don't need to load it, apparently `tidymodels` loads it (and `parsnip`) automatically ...)

```r
library(tidymodels)
fit <- linear_reg()  %>%  
    set_engine("lm") %>%  
    fit(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
fit %>% tidy()
fit %>% glance()
```

Comment: Oh, I now seem it was a silly mistake, and cheers for your pointers on the best practices.